# A case sensitive Error of not finding object 'X' in partykit::ctree when there is not even an object X

Tags: party

library(party)
library(ggparty) 
fit_ctree<-partykit::ctree(Distance_dich~.,
+                  data=t_train,
+                  maxdepth = 5)
Error in .ctree_test_internal(x = x, X = X, ix = NULL, Xleft = Xleft,  : 
  object 'X' not found

> Why am i getting this error if there is not even 'X' in the code?

Comment: Hi welcome to the site! Please provide a minimal self-contained example that replicates the error (e.g., based on one of the built-in data sets in R or partykit), then we can have a look.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem. Seems related to logical variables in our case. Worked with as.numeric() of the logical vars.

Comment: Based on this answer,  I fixed it in dplyr with df %>% mutate(across(where(is.logical), as.integer))